# SSH keys deleted from home folder after reboot

Tags: nas, root, ssh-keys, persistence, home-folder

First time poster and massive unix/linux novice here.

I have a Western Digital My Cloud NAS, which runs (I believe) some version of Debian. I've got a remote backup account with Rsync.net, and want to run daily backups using **rsync** from the NAS to the remote server.

I have full ssh access to the NAS. I've successfully generated the public and private keys using `ssh-keygen -t rsa`, and by default these are being placed in `/home/root/.ssh/id_rsa`. After which, I copy the public key to the remote server and can successfully **ssh** into the server from the NAS without a password. Testing with **rsync** works like a charm. A cronjob is then added to run a rsync bash script every day - so far so good.

However, on reboot the .ssh folder and all the keys are removed from the `/home/root/` folder - I assume that entire folder gets wiped on reboot, as do folders like `/root/` and others.

#### How do I prevent the `/home/root/` folder from resetting every reboot?

Alternatively, I thought a good idea would be to use a new location for the ssh keys, and define the new folder using `AuthorizedKeysFile` in the  sshd_config file. However, other than user shares (i.e, `/shares/`) I can't seem to find a directory that doesn't get wiped upon reboot.

Any ideas?

Comment: "I can't seem to find a directory that doesn't get wiped upon reboot." - then it's not a very useful nas :->

Comment: This question should be converted to one that inquires about persistent storage across reboots on this specific brand-and-model of NAS. It is misleading in its present form. The tags `ssh`, `backup` and `rsync` are also not the real domains of this problem -- they are probably `nas`, `persistence` etc.

Comment: @nik - thanks! Tags updated. Will update the question if needed as soon as I'm back at my desktop, but I think the "ssh keys" portion of my question is still valid - the solution may very well be that I need to change where my ssh keys are stored.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found a solution, which consists of the following steps.

1. Since /home/root is reset each time after the reboot, we need to store id_rsa in a place, for example, in folder /shares/private, so that we can copy it to /home/root after each reboot.
2. create a crontab job following the steps detailed in https://community.wd.com/t/additions-to-crontab-reverting/98317/52 . Please look at Grauwind's answer.
3. Let the crontab job copy /shares/private/id_rsa to /home/root before your backup to your remote server. For example, if your backup to the remote server takes place at 6AM in the morning, set your crontab job to copy /shares/private/id_rsa to /home/root at 5AM would be sufficient.

Hope this helps.